# ShuffleJS cannot read property 'textContent' of null

Tags: javascript, shuffle

I'm learning [ShuffleJS](https://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/) to use it in a project, but I'm running into problems with the *search* functionality. When I'm trying to search for my items, I keep getting this error:

> Cannot read property 'textContent' of null

I grabbed the search code from the [docs](https://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/#advanced-filters), but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Here's some code of my search functionality:

> HTML

```
<section class="search">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="search" id="search" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="grid">
      <div class="box green" data-groups='["green"]' data-title="blue">green</div>
      <div class="box red" data-groups='["red"]' data-title="red">red</div>
      <div class="box green" data-groups='["green"]' data-title="blue">green</div>
      <div class="box red" data-groups='["red"]' data-title="red">red</div>
      <div class="box green" data-groups='["green"]' data-title="blue">green</div>
      <div class="box red" data-groups='["red"]' data-title="red">red</div>
      <div class="col-md-2 my-sizer"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

> JS

```
const Shuffle = window.Shuffle;
const element = $('#grid');
const sizer = $('.my-sizer');

const shuffle = new Shuffle(element, {
  itemSelector: '.box',
  sizer
})

$('#search').on('keyup', (e) => {
  var searchText = e.target.value.toLowerCase();

  shuffle.filter((element, shuffle) => {
    var titleElement = element.querySelector('.box');
    var titleText = titleElement.textContent.toLowerCase().trim(); // <= this is where the error is thrown

    return titleText.indexOf(searchText) !== -1;
  });
})
```

I've also attempted to copy and paste their example JS file [here](https://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/js/demos/homepage.js), but I get the same error mentioned above.

I've also reproduced the code written above in a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/NeroSonic/pen/eYdZpQp)!

Would anyone know where the problem is? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your filter function, it seems `element` is already a `div` with the class `box`.  So there's no need to look within `element` for an element with class `box`, as you've already got it.

So you can replace

```js
    var titleElement = element.querySelector('.box');
    var titleText = titleElement.textContent.toLowerCase().trim(); // <= this is where the error is thrown
```

with

```js
    var titleText = element.textContent.toLowerCase().trim();
```